# Are all solutions of a differential equation function in the true sense of the term.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have a differential equation $f(x,y,y_1,...,y_n)=0$.Then we say that $\phi:X\to \mathbb R$ is a solution if $f(x,\phi,\phi_1,...,\phi_n)=0$,where $X\subset \mathbb R$.But sometimes we get solutions which are not functions of $x$ but a relation between $x,y$,for example $x^2+\log(xy)=\sin(1/y)$,clearly $y$ is not a function of $x$ in proper sense of the term '$\operatorname{function}$'.But still we call it a solution of the differential equation.Another example $x\frac{dy}{dx}=y$,whose solution set includes $x=0$ line as a singular solution,but it does not define any function.So why do we still call it a solution.It seems to me that the definition of solution of a differential equation is not rigorous.What is the way by which it can be properly defined?

Comment: I cannot understand your argument. If there is a relationship between $x$ and $y$ then $x$ is function of $y$ and vice versa $y$ is function of $x$. For exemple, of course $x=0$ is not a function but is a particular value given to $x$. But If you say "The relationship between $x$ and $y$ is $x=0$ ", this means that $x=0$ for any value of $y$. This is a function, namely $x(y)=0$ , which is a wellknown function.

Comment: In the example $x^2+\log(xy) = \sin(1/y)$,$y$ is an implicitly defined function. It may not have a closed form expression but it is non the less a function, and we can compute the values of $y$ for each $x$ using numerical methods. 

$x = 0$ on its own doesn't define a solution, but a solution $y$ can take any values at zero.

Comment: @JJacquelin what does the definition of function say given a value of $x$ I get a single value of $y$ but for $x=0$ there are infinitely many $y$'s.Likewise $x^2+y^2=1$ is not a function because $y=sqrt(1-x^2),-sqrt(1-x^2)$ which is multivalued.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst not for any such implicit relation can we get a function is some nbd,for example $x^2+y^2=1$ does not define any function on any nbd of $(1,0)$ or $(-1,0)$.

Comment: this is true. In order to call it a function, the implicit equation has to define a $y(x)$ for every point in the domain of the differential equation. It is ok to have two or more solutions to an implicit equation, we then have a number of solutions to our DE.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst So,why do we call $x=0$ a solution even when it does not define any function implicitly.

Comment: a solution has to be a pair $(x,y)$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst What do you mean by that?Do you mean a point $(1,2)$ like that?

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst or are you trying to mean $(x,f(x))$,where $x\in X\subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: the second one is what I mean

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Then why do the books define a function $y=f(x)$ is a solution.

Comment: it is equivalent because you then have your set of pairs $(x,f(x)$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst I'm sorry,$(x,f(x))$ is a solution and $f$ is a solution makes the same sense i think.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Then in what way can $x=0$ be treated as solution

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst can the domain of $f$ be any subset of $\mathbb R$ even a single point for example ${0}$ as in case of $x=0$.

Comment: the domain of $f$ has to be the domain specified by the differential equation

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst How...................................................................

Comment: @Kishalay Sarkar. A multivalued function is a function. They are a lot of kind of functions. Multivalued functions are among them. $y(x)=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is the explicit form of function which equivalent implicit form is $y^2+x^2=1$. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultivaluedFunction.html .

Comment: @JJacquelin Refer to the line  While these "functions" are not functions in the normal sense.(From the link you suggested),they are only named functions,But here we are actually talking of functions.

Comment: No. If you want to restrict your question to only single-valued functions you should write this restriction in your question. You didn't write it, so it is implicit that the ODE have to be solved for its general solution as usual. Of course, if you are looking only for single-valued functions, my above comments are out, but in many cases of various ODEs you are lossing some solutions.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Are we talking about multivalued function here?

Comment: @JJacquelin you can consider it as two different functions instead of a multivalued function.

Comment: @Kishalay Sarkar. Instead of $y(x)=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ if you prefer to write that $y(x)$ is the union of $y_1(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $y_2(x)=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ that's up to you. All this is equivalent to write the implicit form $y^2+x^2=1$.

Comment: @JJacquelin I am treating the as two different functions that satisfy the DE instead of using the term multivalued.